# Pass array of objects to template in Go lang

Tags: arrays, go

I'm tried to send an array of object to template in Golang but do not pass the array to template, this is my code:

```
foldersVar := []folder{
    folder{FolderName: "OP10", Path: "C:op10"},
    folder{FolderName: "OP14", Path: "C:op14"},
}

_template.Execute(&body, struct {
    Test    string
    Folders []folder
}{
    Test:    "Prueba",
    Folders: foldersVar,
})

err = smtp.SendMail(hostAndport, auth, from, to, body.Bytes())
```

And my template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>


    <h2>Estas carpetas no se estan respaldando</h2>
    <h3>{{.Test}}</h3>
    {{ range .Folders }}
    <li>{{ .FolderName }}</li>
    {{end}}
</body>
</html>
```

Actually, works only send Test variable but with Folders var not working.

help me please
Thanks.

Comment: Do I understand it correctly, you think that the list items from the array are not processed by the code/template? But it would create `...<h3>Prueba</h3><li>OP10</li><li>OP14</li>...` so the array is taken. There is a tag missing around <li> elements, e.g. <ul> for an unordered list, but that is a different topic. Perhaps you could explain what the observed error symptom is and what you expect instead?

Comment: It works fine: https://go.dev/play/p/ZOQV1-YWquj can you clarify the problem?